# How to avoid font packages not related to language designated

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, fonts, language-support

I am upgrading from Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 to Ubuntu 17.10. As part of the new packages to be installed, I see a list of font packages on several Asian languages that I did not asked, nor were previously installed on my computer because my system language is English (even I use Spanish for my documents).

So, how can I avoid installing (in the first place) these packages, that I mercilessly will delete after the upgrading process finishes?

(I am very comfortable with command-line usage, if it is the case.)

Answer (score 1):

What you noticed was probably the effect of the fact that the `fonts-indic` package is installed by default in 17.10. To remove those extra packages, try these commands:

```
sudo apt purge fonts-indic
sudo apt autoremove
```

I'm not aware of a way to prevent them from being installed to begin with.

Comment: Well, at least now I know they come pre-installed, which is something to mention to the developers. Thank you.

Comment: @celiapgt: They don't come pre-installed by accident.

Comment: @gunnar-jalmarsson Wrll, maybe not "by-accident" but wrongly added as default, because in a fresh installation there they are, and I had set my keyboard language = Spanish latam, and my region= Latam (Latinamerica, México). So they are preinstalled. Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: hahaha, of course. Not by-accident, but as in a non desirable, non-predicted, non programmed way. Every fresh install that I need to do (not setting the Southeast Asia region, but North America!) I end up with these fonts.

Comment: [This](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center/issues/82) is probably a related issue.

Comment: Yes, it is related, @gunnar-hjalmarsson.